# Trouble validating a form in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I reaaaally don´t know what else to do but come here and ask you guys. Heres the situation:

models.py

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    """ Generic vote model """

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    cache = CacheVoteManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s : %s' % (self.user.username, self.question.question)

 class OptionVote(Vote):
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

forms.py

```
  class OptionChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
  """ Custom model choice field for options """
  widget = forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'c-opt'})
  def label_from_instance(self, obj):   
      return mark_safe(
          '<span class="c-opt-img">%s</span><span class="c-opt-name">%s</span>'
          % (obj.media_content.draw_create_widget() , obj.name))

 class OptionVoteForm(ModelForm):
     """ Form to vote in a option-based question """
     option = OptionChoiceField(queryset=OptionVote.objects.none(), 
                            empty_label=None)
     class Meta:
         model = OptionVote
         exclude = ['user', 'question']
     def __init__(self, options=None, *args, **kwargs):
         super(OptionVoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         if options:
             self.fields['option'].queryset = options
```

views.py

```
form = OptionVoteForm(request.POST)
form.is_valid()
>> FALSE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I have tried to see the errors in the form and there seems to be no one. I have put some flags on the form's clean method, and they don´t get called. Sames goes for clean method in OptionChoiceField.

The following code in the view

```
print 'PRINTING ERRORS: ' + str(form.errors)
    for field in form:
        print str(field.label_tag()) + ': ' + str(field.errors)
```

returns:

```
 PRINTING ERRORS: 
 <label for="id_option_0">Option</label>:
```

please help me out here, i´m reaaally stuck in this one.

**EDIT**
when i try to do

```
form = OptionVoteForm(request.POST)
print form
```

i get the following error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'all'
ExceptionLocation: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __iter__, line 882
```

oh, and btw, I´m using django 1.3

Comment: Have you tried using form.errors after you do form.is_valid()?

Comment: yes, check the 'PRINTING ERRORS' statement. That is called at if form.is_valid(): ... else: [here]

Comment: What kind of output are you seeing if you do `print form` after `form = OptionVoteForm(request.POST)`

Comment: I just added to the original question what it say when I do so :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overriding the default constuctor so it accepts an queryset, so you should do:

```
qs = OptionVote.objects.all()
form = OptionVoteForm(qs, request.POST)
```

Comment: I think this may be the winner

Comment: weird thing is I had already tried OptionVoteForm(request.POST, options=qs)... this feels like a bonus, but why that wouldn´t work?